# True Crypt Alternative For Encrypting Drives

Tags: windows-7, security, encryption, 7-zip

I have Windows 7 Pro and as such, bitlocker won't work for me. I have some sensitive information which I have locked with an AES-256 key in a 7zip folder, but I would like to encrypt my entire drive as an added measure. True crypt which had been the leading open source software for such a job has been discontinued and is no longer considered secure according to its authors. Does anyone know of a good open source alternative from a reliable source such as sourceforge?

Comment: VeraCrypt (the first search result from searching for the answer to this question on Google) is a free disk encryption software that is based on TrueCrypt 7.1a. VeraCrypt can mount TrueCrypt volumes. It also can convert them to VeraCrypt format. [VeraCrypt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/veracrypt/) can be downloaded from SourceForge.net.  Also see this question: [Alternatives to TrueCrypt?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/4539/alternatives-to-truecrypt).

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com//help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: There is a how-to-geek [article mentioning 3 alternatives](https://www.howtogeek.com/203708/3-alternatives-to-the-now-defunct-truecrypt-for-your-encryption-needs/). Googling yields other web pages mentioning alternatives but I doubt their credibility.

Answer (score 2):

Vera crypt is one of the many great alternatives to True Crypt. The developers are looking at the published issues with Tera crypt and patches are expected (for those that have not already been fixed) within the next few months.
Vera crypt branches the original Tera crypt code and so is very similar but with a few changes including an improvement that makes it about 300 more times harder to crack with brute force than the True source encryption. It is able to interact with true crypt folders and is free.

PC & Tech Authority's Magazine did a great article on this in the August 2015 issue (pg 108,109).

Download Here: https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/releases/view/616110

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum and  did not realise.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their answers. Next time I will post to the software stack exchange. I did not know that it existed as I've mainly used the electronics and sometimes superuser one. Thanks

Comment: Sam, and what are those other "many"? VeraCrypt seems to be so far the only one, and it's not stable enough, and not well mainained.

Comment: I'm afraid I have not used any of the alternatives but a simple google search "veracrypt alternatives"  reveals several options.